# A shooting game; target hit both when shot

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

In a shooting game the probabiltiies that Roger and Joel will hit a target are 2/3 and 3/4 respectively. What is the probability that the target is hit when both shoot at it?

The answer among the choices is 11/12

These are both independent probabiltiies and my solution is
2/3 * 3/4 = 6/12 = 1/2

Even if they are mutually exclusive events its
2/3 + 3/4 = 17/12

answer is still wrong. What kind of event is in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(\text{Roger hit or Joel hit})=P(\text{Roger hit})+P(\text{Joel Hit})-P(\text{Roger hit and Joel hit})$

So the probability is $\dfrac 23+\dfrac 34-\dfrac 12=\boxed{\dfrac{11}{12}}$.

The event is not mutally exclusive, and mutally exclusive simply means P(A and B)=0. However, they are independent.